# How to click each item of recycler view of android app using appium test case

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

How to click each item of recycler view of android app using appium test case.

We can click random recycler view of android but haven't found solution to clicking each of the recycler view item .

Comment: follow this it will helps you https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-find-all-the-elements-in-list-view/5767/6

Comment: I'd suggest you also look into AndroidX Test, which is supported by Google to test apps as an alternative. Look here: https://youtu.be/wYMIadv9iF8?t=682

Comment: @Yatin Did you get answer??

Comment: @MangeshSambare : No , havent got yet